# Delete values from Sharepoint 2010 user profile using c#

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am able to add and edit values in sharepoint user profile . But i m unable to delete values from UP . For example i have added user profile property as "Certifications" i can add values in to the UP using C# code . I want to delete values from userprofile using C# code.

Comment: Can you please post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some tests in my environement, this works :

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://xxx/"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
       try
       {
           SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
           UserProfileManager userProfileManager = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);
           UserProfile userprofile = userProfileManager.GetUserProfile("your login");
           //Set value
           userprofile["Department"].Value = "StackOverflow";
           userprofile.Commit();
           //Remove value
           userprofile["Department"].Value = "";
           userprofile.Commit();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          //TO DO
      }
   }
}
```

If you provide us more information, I can edit my code for a more elaborate sample.